# Using soup.find() to find a span

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the shipping price of a product on AliExpress, the info I need is "Envío: 378.99 MXN$" 
Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="product-shipping-price" data-spm-anchor-id=
"a2g0o.detail.10000016.i3.45933e3aW1Bdt1">
   <span class="bold" data-spm-anchor-id=
  "a2g0o.detail.10000016.i2.45933e3aW1Bdt1"> == $0
      "Envío: 378.99 MXN$"
      "&nbsp;"
    </span>
</div>
```

I tried to use:

```
price = soup.find("span", {"class": "bold"}
```

But then I don't know ho to refer to the info I need

Comment: do you mean something like `get_text()`? https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Comment: Could you post the URL to the website that you're scraping?

Comment: Here’s the website https://m.es.aliexpress.com/item/32956769262.html?trace=wwwdetail2mobilesitedetail

Answer (score 0):

Just doing the following would help. It would spit out the data you need.

```
>>> price.text
```

Comment: The problem is that 'price' returns 'None'